# How to tell if PuTTY is using my ssh key from Pageant or not

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm trying to set up an ssh key and use it via PuTTY/pageant. I've added the key into my .ssh/authorized_keys file, I have my key loaded in pageant, and I have "Attempt authentication using Pageant" checked in PuTTY. But when I try to connect, it still prompts me for a password.

How can I tell where in the process something is going wrong? Is there some details about PuTTY's connection attempts I can look at to verify if its trying my pageant key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on PuTTY window title and select *Event Log*.

Look for entry:

> Pageant is running. Requesting keys.

And inspect following entries.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!